# Cross compiling toolchain using crosstool-ng

Tags: glibc, crosstool-ng

I am trying to build a Linux environment with glibc version 2.5 to compile C code using crosstool-ng. But I cannot find glibc version 2.5 in configuration for some reason. Does anyone know how to fix that?

And I tried to use older version glibc 2.2 and got the errors when building the library.

```
 Installing C library headers & start files
[EXTRA]    Configuring C library
[ERROR]    configure: error: GNU libc requires kernel header files from
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing C library headers & start files'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@257]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_backend_once[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@354]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_backend[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@149]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_libc_start_files[scripts/build/libc/glibc-eglibc.sh-common@66]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@638]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/crosstool-ng/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.20.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 24:43.44)
[24:45] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Here are all configurations I modified:

```
Target Option
    Target Architecture    x86
OS
    Target OS      Linux
    Linux kernel version  -  2.6.27.62(actually need 2.6.18 but cannot find it)

Binary utilities
    binutils version 2.25

C-library
    C library    -- glibc 2.2    need glibc 2.5

C compiler   -- gcc version 4.4.5
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my configurations and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the build.log file?

Comment: Any luck yet? I have the same issue.